# i18n message extraction in CRA using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I'm trying to get i18n message extracted (defined by `react-intl`'s `defineMessages`) to work properly in a CRA using TypeScript.
I've got an existing react app bootstrapped by CRA with a couple of hundrets of lines of code. So rewriting the application w/o TypeScript isn't an option.

---

Here's what i've tried so far:

## First Attempt

Following this [guide](https://medium.com/@shalkam/create-react-app-i18n-the-easy-way-b05536c594cb) in order to get it to work.
When closely following the guide (although `react-intl-cra` is deprecated) the language files will generate properly.
However if you create the app using `create-react-app react-intl-example --typescript` and change the `script` to

```
"extract:messages": "react-intl-cra 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' -o 'src/i18n/messages/messages.json'"
```

it will break with a compiler error.

## Second Attempt

Since `react-intl-cra` was refering to a `react-app-rewired` solution, I've tried adding it alongside `customize-cra` and `babel-plugin-react-intl` to a freshly generated CRA (using TS). However no luck there as well and after some short period of research I found that it's [officially not supported](https://github.com/formatjs/babel-plugin-react-intl/issues/48).

## Third attempt:

Adding `extract-react-intl-messages` to my project and running:

```sh
$ npx extract-messages -l=en,ja -o app/translations -d en --flat false 'src/**/!(*.test).tsx'
```

failed with an error as well.

---

I ran out of ideas, hence I came here to ask. From what I've seen TypeScript has been well advertised in the last couple of years and I don't think I have to justify that React is still pretty hyped. Moreover I can't imagine, that i18n is an uncommon concern in application development.
However I wasn't able to find any up-to-date guide or anything useful on npmjs.com.

## TL;DR;

What I need:

- Extract messages from `defineMessages` from `react-intl` into json files
- Must work in a CRA using `--typescript`
- Should not utilize `npm run eject`

What I've tried:

- [`react-intl-cra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-cra)
- [`react-app-rewired`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) + [`customize-cra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/customize-cra) + [`babel-plugin-react-intl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-intl)
- [`extract-react-intl-messages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-react-intl-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained here: https://github.com/akameco/extract-react-intl-messages#typescript

Basically you need to

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-typescript @babel/preset-react`

and add

`@babel/preset-typescript`

to your `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
}
```

Then you can run

`npm run extract-messages 'src/**/*.[jt]sx'`